# How to call coinbase api methods from codeigniter controller class?

Tags: php, codeigniter, coinbase-api, coinbase-php

I have added [coinbase php](https://github.com/coinbase/coinbase-php) library inside application/third_party folder. Now I want to add a normal php file using that library in codeigniter root folder to add content to log file and send  email to notify about transactions?

- Is it okay if add a core php file in root? How would I require that
  coinbase plugin and load database into the said php file?
- Is it a good practice in mvc? What are other alternatives?

UPDATE:
I created a controller in application/controlers with below code

```
class Coinbase extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();   
    }

    function readnotifications()
    {
        echo APPPATH;
        require_once(APPPATH.'third_party/coinbase-php/vendor/autoload.php');
        use Coinbase\Wallet\Client;
}
}
```

I get below error.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE)

UPDATE2:

$config['composer_autoload'] = APPPATH.'third_party/coinbase-php/vendor/autoload.php';

```
class Coinbase extends CI_Controller
{
    function readnotifications()
    {

$apiKey = "sss ";
$apiSecret =  "sss";
        namespace Coinbase\Wallet;
        use Coinbase\Wallet\Client;
        use Coinbase\Wallet\Configuration;
        use Coinbase\Wallet\Enum\Param;
$configuration = Configuration::apiKey($apiKey, $apiSecret);
$client = Client::create($configuration);
$authenticity = $client->verifyCallback($raw_body, $signature); // boolean
}
}
```

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'Coinbase' (T_STRING), expecting \ (T_NS_SEPARATOR)

Any idea how to resolve?

Comment: what version of codeigniter are you using

Comment: I don't get it. Are you trying to create a controller and are having issues loading a third party lib that might not be ci compatible (namespaced)? Because if you just want a php page you don't need ci and you can access it's db through some hacky ways but I don't see why you don't just create a controller.  Having said that no, it's not mvc so you can't consider it good or bad practice because it's something else entirely.

Comment: @RahulSingh CI 3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you application/config/config.php search for `$config['composer_autoload']` and set you third party package autoload.php file path as its value

```
$config['composer_autoload'] = '/path/to/vendor/autoload.php';
```

Then you can simple use any of your package classes like this

```
function readnotifications()
{
        $client = Coinbase\Wallet\Client;
}
```

Also have a look at this https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/autoloader.html

Comment: thanks for responding. I updated my question. Can you please check it?

Comment: Don't use namespace and use statements. They should only be used at the starting of any php files according to PSR. Instead use fully qualified class names. Like  $configuration = \Coinbase\Wallet\Configuration::apiKey($apiKey, $apiSecret); Give it a try